# How to create directories inside /tmp for each process on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, linux, caching, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So we have an instance on Elastic Beanstalk (64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.3 running Python 3.4) that has 3 concurrent processes running. I have a library that caches data, but I'm running into errors with the three processes trying to access the same cached data.

The solution I came up with was to use the process ID (PID) in the cache path, so no two processes shared a cache (ex: /tmp/.prose/3443, where 3443 is the PID).

I tried using a container command, but it seems as though those do not run for each individual process, only at deployment.

I have also tried various methods of `os.mkdir`, `os.makedirs`, `os.system('sudo mkdir ...')`, and without sudo, I always get a permission denied error. All of these mkdir calls are followed by the equivalent `os.system("chmod 777 -R {1}".format(cache_dirname))`, or `os.chmod(path, 0o777)`. I've tried to call it with sudo, but can't type in the password. I've considered editing the sudoers file, but that edit would have to take place programmatically in order to be present when we re-deployed a new instance, so that seems quite difficult.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I should do in order to create these directories on the fly on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Check who is the owner of `/tmp/.prose/` directory. Looks like you are a victim of sticky bit, which will prevent anyone other than the owner of the directory (and root) to create a directory.

Comment: /tmp/ should only be used to read, and to delete your own files. Attempts to write manually (create files, folders) will change the default permissions.

Comment: Root is the owner.

Comment: I'm guessing I should change the owner of the `/tmp/.prose` directory? If so, which user do I change it to?

Comment: Set to the same user which runs the python stuff